# angular formly form with multiple steps and nested fields

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formly

I got assigned to the project that uses formly to build forms. most of them are either plain single page forms or forms out of jsonSchema. I got asked to research  nested forms with tabs etc.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-formly-ouzzaa?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

It seems to be working except it does not create nested objects in the model. I need to get something like this:

```
{
   category1: {
      subcat1: {
         field1: 'value',
         field2: 'value'
      },
      subcat2: {
         field1: 'value',
         field2: 'value'
      }
   },
   category2: {
   ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add FormGroup with FormArray as following...

```
  this.FormGroupName = fb.group({
    id: [null],
    //default form controls put here
    CatgoryList1: this.fb.group({
        List1: this.fb.array([
          this.fb.group({
            Field1: [null], //you can apply validation here
            Field2: [null]
          })
        ]),
        //and so on..
    }),
    CatgoryList2: this.fb.group({
        List2: this.fb.array([
          this.fb.group({
            Field3: [null],
            Field4: [null]
          })
        ]),
        //and so on..
    }),
    //and so on..
});
```

You can also push into form dynamically as following...

```
this.CatList.push(this.initCatListGroup_Cat1());


get CatList() {
    return this.FormGroupName.get('CatgoryList1').get('List1') as FormArray;
}

initCatListGroup_Cat1() {
    return this.fb.group({
      Field1: [null],
      Field2: [null]
    })
}
```

I hope it is helpful for you. :)

Comment: Yeah I have started like this as well and it seems to be working, but requires to manually build form which kind of destroys the idea of using formly. I am currently working on building this structure based on JSON.

Meanwhile I used the hideExpression to hide subsections when they should not be displayed

Comment: I have checked and i want to share this link with you which is fully customization as you want. I hope it is helpful for you. [Click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-datatable) :)